# How to call controller in observer or block or helper?

Tags: magento2, controllers

How can I call controller in my observer like my observer function is this

```
  public function abcd{
              //some code///
     how to call controller here?
}
```

The controller function is execute and also there are parameters to pass ([www.demo.com/test/test/test/order_id/1234](http://www.demo.com/test/test/test/order_id/1234))  then how can I trigger or execute the controller?

one way is that I can simply use curl call to that controller but is there any other way?

Comment: If you want then look into this https://viniciusmuniz.com/en/send-post-request-without-form/ Might help you. But I will suggest whatever you are doing with the controller do it with block and make a common file for both

Answer (score 0):

It is generally bad idea to execute controller in observer. You can move the method to a helper class and [inject](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html#injection-types-used-in-magento) the helper to the observer.

Comment: yes i know but is there any way?